# Recovering credential data from a master DB backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, master-system-database

On a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, a misconfigured credential used as a SSIS proxy for an SSA job was dropped before I could look at the system views to figure out when it was originally misconfigured.

I restored a backup of the `master` DB under an alternate user DB name to see if I can extract the data but it appears the `sys.credentials` view is looking at the live `master` DB instead of the restored DB even with the DB context set to the restored DB.

Is there an alternate method to retrieve the data from this and other system views from a backup without the usual DR methodology?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a restored master DB to try this, but running the statement of the view definition (with the references to master. changed to your user db name) should be a step in the right direction.
You can get the statement by running 
`sp_helptext [sys.credentials]`